# hash from url gets removed before page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-hooks

I'm trying to capture hash from url such as this `https://examplesite.com/page#time=1/12/2019&index=12344&access_token=JWT` but before I get the chance to capture it, the `access_token` in that url gets removed and upon the site load, I can't capture the hash using `window.location.hash`

My example is inside a React functional component, using React hooks:

```js
  const watchHash = () => {
    if (window.location.hash.includes('access_token')) {
      console.log(window.location.hash);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', watchHash);
    watchHash();
    return window.removeEventListener('hashchange', watchHash);
  }, []);
```

The above code watches the hash and only prints the url that doesn't includes `access_token`, such as this `#time=1/12/2019&index=12344`,
event if try to `console.log(window.location.hash)` outside the hook and at the top of the component itself.

I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this, help appreciated.

Comment: Where in the application of yours are you adding the event listener? If you attach the event listener after the url is changed, the event will obviously not be emitted.

Comment: @StephanOlsen This event listener hook is inside the `Login` component, and the ur loads this component.

Comment: And which part of your application removes the hash form your url? Either way, you need to move the event listener higher up in your component tree, to be able to attach the listener before the event occurs.

Comment: @StephanOlsen I don't know what's removing it and if something is removing it then why leave the other hashes? Also, I got it to the top component, still removes the hash before I could capture it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some kind of authentication library, which is probably removing the access_token from the hash. Without a seeing some code it's hard to help you further.